# how to replace a column of data with another column from another table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have two tables, tbl1(col1, col2, col3), tbl2(col1). I need to replace the data of tbl1.col1 with the data from tbl2.col1. My problem is there is no common field to join the two tables. Is it possible to write a query to do the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  I'm not really sure what kind of data you have where there's no way to link Table2 and Table1, though:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL)
       ,Col1
    FROM
       Tbl1

)
,T2 AS
(
   SELECT
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL)
       ,Col1
    FROM
       Tbl2

)

UPDATE
    T1
SET
    Col1 = T2.col1
FROM 
    T1
INNER JOIN
    T2
       ON T1.RN = T2.RN
```